# Spring Test DBUnit does not create a dataset

Tags: java, spring-boot, dbunit, spring-boot-test, spring-test-dbunit

I use `SpringBoot`, `Spring Test DBUnit`.
I wrote a test:

`ShortenerAppTest`:

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ShortenerApp.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ShortenerAppTest {
   @Test
   public void contextLoads() {
   }
}
```

`repositories/AbstractRepositoryTest`:

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@TestExecutionListeners(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ShortenerApp.class)
@DirtiesContext
abstract class AbstractRepositoryTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
}
```

`repositories/LinkRepositoryTest`:

```
@DatabaseSetup(LinkRepositoryTest.DATASET)
@DatabaseTearDown(type = DatabaseOperation.DELETE_ALL, value = LinkRepositoryTest.DATASET)
public class LinkRepositoryTest {
   final static String DATASET = "classpath:datasets/link-table.xml";
   private final static Long LINK_1_ID = 100500L;
   private final static String LINK_1_TEXT = "http://www.www.ya.ru";

@Autowired
LinkRepository repository;

@Test
public void findOneExisting() {
    System.out.println(DATASET);
    Optional<Link> got = repository.findOne(LINK_1_ID);
    assertThat(got.isPresent(), equalTo(true));
    Link linkFromDb = got.get();
    Link link = new Link();
    link.setId(LINK_1_ID);
    link.setUrl(LINK_1_TEXT);
    assertThat(linkFromDb, equalTo(link));
}
}
```

And `dataset`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataset>
    <links id="100500" url="http://www.ya.ru"/>
    <links id="100501" url="http://www.mail.ru"/>
    <links id="100502" url="http://www.google.com"/>
</dataset>
```

`application-test.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

But, when I try run my test, I have `java.lang.NullPointerException`.
I guess this is because the database does not have the necessary records.

It can be seen from the log that he is trying to use a real database, not a test base. For some reason, it does not read my test configuration.
[image]
What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**:

When I write in `ShortenerAppTest` like this:

```
@DatabaseSetup("/datasets/link-table.xml")
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
    DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class})
public class ShortenerAppTest {
@Autowired
LinkRepository repository;
@Test
public void contextLoads() {
   Optional<Link> got = repository.findOne(100500L);
    System.out.println(got);
}
}
```

And It's work, but I still get an error in my `LinkRepositoryTest`

Comment: why do you need this statement? spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

Comment: @TalAvissar, Has removed. But did not solve my problem in any way

Comment: The error you are showing is that the drop sequence links_seq  is not working. and then it creates it. so what is the problem? this error is not a problem.

Comment: @TalAvissar, `links_seq` i use in real enviroment with `PostgeSQL`, not in test! In test, I use H2 DB. The problem is that 3 records in the table should be created on the dataset, but they are not created, and therefore the test does not work.